# twilio api sending whatsapp messages with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio

pleas help I'm working in WinForms form app and I'm trying to send whatsapp messages to client.
I installed twilio api package in my project but when i'm trying to import twilio name space I can't

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Twilio;// but i can import this name space
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;//I can't import this name space
using Twilio.Types;//I can't import this name space
```

pleas help me to know what to do
i'm using vs2015 asp.net and installed  twilio v 5.8.3

Comment: you need to install the nuget package, did you install it?

Comment: thaaaaaanks that was me problem

Comment: Ill post this as answer, please upvote and mark as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the Twilio nuget package and this will be resolved.